Wordpress - How to remove nofollow tags from header menu links?
I've seen that the header menu links have a nofollow attribute.
I checked header php, and couple of other files in theme editor but couldn't find location of these links. How should i supposed to remove these tags from menu links? I'm using astra theme.

Open functions.php: Navigate to your child theme's directory and open functions.php file.
Add Code: Insert the following code snippet:
function remove_nofollow_from_menu_links( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['rel'] = '';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'remove_nofollow_from_menu_links', 10, 3 );

Using a Plugin
Install Plugin: Install and activate a plugin like "Menu Link Attributes" or similar.
Access Plugin Settings: Once activated, navigate to Appearance > Menu in your WordPress dashboard.
Edit Link: Select the menu item you want to edit, and you should now see an option to add or remove link attributes including rel.

Thanks for reply, When I try to insert the code, I'm getting "Scrape key check failed" error. I wan't to solve this without plugin if possible.

check this for that https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-wordpress-theme-editor-scrape-key-check-failed-error/
